# How to average a List<List<double>> for each inner entry?

Tags: c#, linq, list, average, montecarlo

I am doing a MonteCarlo Simulation and am nearly finished writing the code for that part of my application. Ihave the following list:

```
List<List<double>> myFullList = new List<List<double>>();
List<double> myInnerList = new List<double>();

for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfLoops; i++)
{ 
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        // Populate inner list with random numbers
        myInnerList.Add(double myRandomNumber);
    }

    // Add the inner list to the full list
    myFullList.Add(myInnerList);
}
```

The list should look something like this:

```
myFullList[0] = {rand#1,rand#2,rand#3,...,rand#10}
myFulllist[1] = {rand#1,rand#2,rand#3,...,rand#10}
.
.
.
.
myFulllist[1] = {rand#1,rand#2,rand#3,...,rand#10}
```

I need to average that data to form ONE single list that looks something like this:

```
List<double> averagedData = new List<double>();
averagedData = {avg#1, avg#2........avg#10}
```

This output variable will average the data for the same "row" of data in the inner list.

Simple example:

```
innerList[0] = {1,2,3};
innerList[1] = {3,2,1};

fullList = {innerList[0], innerList[1]};

averageList = {2,2,2};
```

Comment: Are you sure that `List<double> myInnerList = new List<double>();` is placed correctly? I'd expect it to be at the beginning of the first `for` loop.

Comment: Some might find `var myFullList = new List<List<double>>()` easier to read. It's certainly easier to type! And there is no ambiguity as to the actual type of `myFullList`.

Comment: AlexD is right. Also, `myInnerList.Add(double myRandomNumber)` doesn't make sense.  I don't think your code would work.  Another thought, why does your requirement have you averaging columns?  You could design your algo to have 3 rows with 2 columns each and achieve the same results. Btw, your wording and choice of sample numbers doesn't clearly convey that you want to average columns, although p.s.w.g did figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are just trying to average each inner list, you can use:

```
List<double> averagedData = myFullList.Select(l => l.Average()).ToList();
```

If you are trying to average the "columns" of data, which seems to be the case from your sample, you could do something like:

```
var averagedData = myFullList[0].Select((v,c) =>
                       myFullList.Average(r => r[c])
                  ).ToList();
```

Comment: In OP's sample, there's two lists in `fullList`, but 3 results in `averageList`. It seems like he wants to average across 'columns' and not the 'rows' so to speak.

Comment: /\ Yes! exactly correct. Reed, I just tried your solution but it averages each list together rather than averaging "across columns", Reed, will try your modified solution.

Comment: Worked Like a charm (second option). If I am not mistaken, I already found this solution online but it was missing the ".ToList()" part. Thanks!!   (Also, as a note: My original sample example was bad because the average is the same "2" with either option)

Comment: @ReedCopsey can you please explain your second code example?  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
var averagedData = myFullList.Select(x => x.Average()).ToList();
```